# What is most advantage of using char instead of 'int'

Tags: c

Below are my codes that convert large letters to small letters and vice versa.

```
#if SOL_2
        char ch;
        char diff = 'A' - 'a';
        //int diff = 'A' - 'a';
        fputs("input your string : ", stdout);

        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                ch += diff;
            }
            else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                ch -= diff;
            }
            else {}

            printf("%c", ch);
        }
#endif
```

Above codes, instead of `char diff = 'A' - 'a'`, I used the `int = 'A' -'a'` and the result was same. Therefore, I thought that using character can save memory since `char` is one byte but `int` is four bytes. I can't think other advantages of it.
I would appreciate it if you let me know other advantages of it.

And What is the main reason of using `char` in order to store character values?
It is because of just memory size problem?

Comment: '*Result was same*' does not necessarily mean that you are correct.

Comment: The result was the same because when you store a small value in a larger space (character in an int), the bits remain the same.  You just have a bunch of leading 0s if it's in an int.  In cases where you perform calculations on variables and you store them as smaller types (like storing an int in a char), you may run the risk of exceeding 8 bits.  Even if this is very brief, you run a great risk of compromising data.

Comment: Using `char` for arithmetics is **always** a bad idea.

Comment: "Don't tell me there's not one bit of difference between uppercase and lowercase, because that's exactly what there is." `if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' || ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ch ^= 0x60;`

Comment: @ikegami: magic numbers and fixed to ASCII - very bad! Does not even work with ISO8859-1

Comment: Also literals such as `'A'` are of type `int` themselves.

Comment: @ikegami, no the OP implicitly assumed that lower case and upper case letters each are contiguous. Otherwise there is nothing that assumes ASCII.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, And that's only the case for ASCII. But I'll rephrase...

Comment: @Olaf, Neither does the OP's. What I posted works for all characters sets for which the OP's version works. I didn't add any assumptions. True, what I posted shouldn't be used in the modern world, but neither should the OP's.

Comment: @ikegami: No. Your code relies on bit 6 being the "uppercase bit". OP uses the difference, which does not presume a specific code.

Comment: @Olaf, No, you are mistaken. The only character set for which the OP's code works is for ASCII. Both of our programs make the same assumption.

Comment: @ikegami: It works for any character set with letters in adjacent, ascending order and with codes less than 128, even if the lower case letters preceed the uppercase or not just differentiated by a single bit. Your code relies on bit 6 ... (I wrote that already)

Comment: @Olaf, I hear what you're saying, but it's wrong. My solution works everywhere the OP's solution works. If you think I'm wrong, prove it: Name one character set where his works and mine doesn't.

Comment: @ikegami: I clearly stated a scenario. COnsider one where the uppercase letters instantly follow the lowercase letters. Note there are quite some non-standardised encodings, e.g. in embedded devices which are designed to conserve memory footprint.

Comment: @Olaf, Oh yeah? Like what? you just gotta name one to prove me wrong.

Comment: @ikegami: Ok: Olaf1 (on my old HC11 board). I used a manual translation preprocessor. Prove me wrong!

Comment: @Olaf, And the OP's doesn't work on Éric1. Funny that. (or EBCIDIC, or UTF-16be, UTF-16le, UTF-32le, UTF-32be, UCS-2le, UCS-2be, UCS-4le, UCS-4be, etc) You're spending so much time creating imaginary problems when you couldn't be pointing out that the OP's code doesn't work with Unicode! It can't even lowercase my name (Éric)

Comment: @ikegami Certainly you meant `ch ^= 0x20;` and not `ch ^= 0x60;` in your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636709/what-is-most-advantage-of-using-char-instead-of-int/38639130#comment64657819_38636709).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Why is using `char` for arithmetics is always a bad idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `int ch` and `int diff`.

- `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Therefore `ch` needs to be `int`.  This is so you can tell the difference between end-of-file and character `0xff`, both of which would be `-1` in a signed byte.  ([reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/getchar#Common_mistake))
- `char` might be `signed` or `unsigned` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/2877364)).  Therefore, you should use `int` for comparisons so that you know you have room for negative values ([`int` is signed by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674753/2877364)).

To answer your specific question, use `char` when you know you have byte data and, yes, you'll most likely save some memory.  Another reason to use `char` (or `wchar_t` or other character types) is to make it clear to the reader of your code that you intend this data to be text and not numeric, if indeed that is the case.  Another use case for `char` is to access individual bytes of a file or other data stream.

Comment: @Olaf, Re "*An the signed-ness of char is implementation defined, not always signed*". That's what cxw said.

Comment: @Olaf the second bullet says "char _might be signed or unsigned_ (see this answer). Therefore, you should use int for comparisons so that you know you have room for negative values (int is signed by default).".

Comment: `EOF` is never `0xff`, because `EOF` must be negative and `0xff` is always the value `255`. When converted to a `char` that by coincidence is and unsigned integer type, might end up to be `255` after that conversion.

Comment: @iRove: My bad, sorry. Thanks for the correction. The false presumption about encoding still remains. There is no specific encoding of signed integers enforced by the standard. However, the first bullet is wrong in that it assumes there actually can be a `char` with value `0xff`. That is only possible if a byte has more than 8 bits or `char` is unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the main reason of using `char` in order to store character values? It is because of just memory size problem?

The primary use of using `char` vs. `int` with **arrays** and **sequences** of characters is space (and processing speed on machines with wide architectures).  If code uses characters limited to an 8-bit range, excessively large data types slow things down.

With *single* instances of a type, `int` is often better as that is typically the "native" type that the processor is optimized for.

Yet optimizing for a single `char` vs `int` (assuming both work in the application) is usually not a fruitful use of your time.  Worry about larger issues and let the compiler optimize the small stuff.

---

Note that `int getchar()` returns *values* in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  These typically 257 different values cannot be store distinctly in a `char`.  Use an `int`

---

C provides `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()`, `tolower()` and is the robust method to handle simple character case conversion.

```
if (isupper(ch)) ch = tolower(ch);
```

Example usage:

```
int ch;   
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
  if (isupper(ch)) {
    ch = tolower(ch);
  }
  else if (islower(ch)) {
    ch = toupper(ch);
  }
  printf("%c", ch);
}
fflush(stdout);
```

---

With [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and every small character encoding I've encounterd, A-Z case conversion can be done by simple toggling a bit.  Notice no magic numbers.

```
ch ^= 'A' ^ 'a';
```

Example usage:

```
int ch;   
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
  if (isalpha(ch)) {
    ch ^= 'A' ^ 'a';
  }
  printf("%c", ch);
}
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you pointed out correctly the character the we use in char are nothing but binary code of 1 byte i.e 256 number each number in binary represent a number mapping to a character (might be not all binary number represent different character it depends which encoding you use) refer unicode encoding , don't just considering only english language consider other language characters as well like chinesse or hindi... and so on .So each character in this language needs to be represented by a number which is standardise by unicode

so the point is when you use char of java it only contains a subset of only  english language alphabets however when you develop a international software which has ability to choose across different languages to display you should use int rather .  However if your scope is only english language char would be the best choice as when you use int it consumes more bits that are unused bit which are been padded off with zero this are just extra bits with no significance to match the length of a int

suppose you have a text in chinesse language opened in editor like notepad and if the character encoding is set to ASCII as ascii has a small charset that is only english A-Z, a-z, 0-9 , space , newline ... like 256 odd characters, you will see wired characters in the file just like a binary file to see the actually content of file you need to change encoding to UTF-8 which uses unicode charset , and now you can see the text

Answer (score 0):

Plase read Standard [6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) and [6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1).

> **If an int can represent all values of the original type [...] the value is converted to an int;**

In

```
char c1 = 'A', c2 = 'Z';
c2 - c1;                   // expression without side effects
```

the expression above, both `x` and `y` are converted to `int` before the subtraction is performed.